# Telegraph.js how can I create an ascii table for each result?

Tags: node.js, telegraf.js

i'm developing a bot and I'm running into a lot of errors
the ascii table does not accept very long text, but when I try to do it, I encounter an error like this

```
C:\Users\Mars\Desktop\sorgubotpro\node_modules\telegraf\core\network\client.js:263
      throw new TelegramError(data, { method, payload })
            ^

TelegramError: 400: Bad Request: message is too long
at C:\Users\Mars\Desktop\sorgubotpro\node_modules\telegraf\core\network\client.js:263:17
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
code: 400,
response: {
ok: false,
error_code: 400,
description: 'Bad Request: message is too long'
},
description: 'Bad Request: message is too long',
parameters: {},
on: {
method: 'sendMessage',
```

to fix this error, open an ascii table for each result. How can I do it separately for each result?